# Ruby replace array list

Tags: ruby

I have two strings:

```
packages="­linux-imag­e-3.2.0-4-­amd64 linux­-libc-dev linux­-headers-3­.2.0-4-amd­64 linux­-headers-3­.2.0-4-com­mon dnsutils mysql-server-5.5"
exclusion="dnsutils mysql-server-5.5"
```

I need a string `pkgs` that has the content of `packages` without `exclusion` like this:

```
pkgs="­linux-imag­e-3.2.0-4-­amd64 linux­-libc-dev linux­-headers-3­.2.0-4-amd­64 linux­-headers-3­.2.0-4-com­mon"
```

I tried the following code:

```
pkgs = packages.gsub!( /(?<!^|,)#{exclusion}(?!,|$)/, '\1')
```

which does not seem to be working. What would be the best working solution in this case?

Comment: from the packages variable, i want to exclude the strings in the exclusion variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
packages="linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64 linux-libc-dev linux-headers-3.2.0-4-amd64 linux-headers-3.2.0-4-common dnsutils mysql-server-5.5"
exclusion="dnsutils mysql-server-5.5"
(packages.split - exclusion.split).join(" ") # => "linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64 linux-libc-dev linux-headers-3.2.0-4-amd64 linux-headers-3.2.0-4-common"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep it simple, you can always split these strings into arrays, and join the difference.

```
(packages.split - exclusion.split).join ' '
```

String's `split` method will default to space characters. This give you two arrays, where you subtract the any values that exist in the both the first and second array from the first array. You then `join` this new array with space characters.

Longer example:

```
packages="linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64 linux-libc-dev linux-headers-3.2.0-4-amd64 linux-headers-3.2.0-4-common dnsutils mysql-server-5.5"
exclusion="dnsutils mysql-server-5.5"


one = packages.split
# >> ["linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64", "linux-libc-dev", "linux-headers-3.2.0-4-amd64", "linux-headers-3.2.0-4-common", "dnsutils", "mysql-server-5.5"]

two = exclusion.split 
# >> ["dnsutils", "mysql-server-5.5"]

difference = one - two
# >> ["linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64", "linux-libc-dev", "linux-headers-3.2.0-4-amd64", "linux-headers-3.2.0-4-common"]

finished = difference.join ' '
# >> "linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64 linux-libc-dev linux-headers-3.2.0-4-amd64 linux-headers-3.2.0-4-common"
```

Comment: what is the explanation of this solution ?

Comment: Does that explanation help?

Answer (score 0):

You need your variables to be arrays, not strings. Then you can just use the `-` operator to "subtract" the items in `exclusion` from `packages`:

```
packages = [ "­linux-imag­e-3.2.0-4-­amd64", 
             "linux­-libc-dev",
             "linux­-headers-3­.2.0-4-amd­64",
             "linux­-headers-3­.2.0-4-com­mon",
             "dnsutils",
             "mysql-server-5.5" ]

exclusion = [ "dnsutils", "mysql-server-5.5" ]

remaining = packages - exclusion
# => [ "­linux-imag­e-3.2.0-4-­amd64", 
#      "linux­-libc-dev",
#      "linux­-headers-3­.2.0-4-amd­64",
#      "linux­-headers-3­.2.0-4-com­mon" ]
```

If you then need the values in a single string, join them together with the `join` method:

```
remaining_str = remaining.join(" ")
# => "­linux-imag­e-3.2.0-4-­amd64 linux­-libc-dev linux­-headers-3­.2.0-4-amd­64 linux­-headers-3­.2.0-4-com­mon"
```